# Iterating Vector of Hashtables using c:forEach

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have Vector of Hashtables and each hash table has two elements with keys 'key1' and 'key2'.

Now in the jsp page i have to iterate those vector and print those values in the hash table using jstl tag `c:forEach`

Could anybody helps how to do that using `c:forEach`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <c:forEach items="${myVector}" var="ht">
    <c:out value="${ht.key1}" />
    <c:out value="${ht.key2}" />
  </c:forEach>
```

Try this way, here you should know the key names.

Answer (score 3):

```
<c:forEach items="${yourVector}" var="ht">
   <c:forEach items="${ht}" var="entry">
       <c:out value="${entry.key}" />
   </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

Btw, use `HashMap` instead of `Hashtable` (and `ArrayList` instead of `Vector`)

Comment: And `ArrayList` instead of `Vector`.